# not to show previous link at the start page and next link at the last page?

Tags: php, pagination

I have to links Next and Previous in Pagination. What I should do so that 'previous' link should hide when I was on the first page and the 'next' link should hide when I was on the last page?
my code for next and previous links is:

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='
.($page-1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';

echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='
.($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
```

Comment: show us your code! http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work well the way your doing it right now, unless you have the specific number of pages.

If you have the total number of pages, you can do this

```
if( $page > 1 ) {
 echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='
.($page-1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Previous</a>';
}
if( $page < $totalPages ) {
 echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='
.($page+1).'&date1='.$_REQUEST["date1"].'&date2='.$_REQUEST["date2"].'">Next</a>';
}
```